# What does this quote mean to you?

Tags: meaning-in-context, quotes

I'm assigned to read the book called *Life at the Bottom* by Theodore Dalrymple, and I'm reading a quote in the book, but I don't really understand it.

> “Such flattery is thus the death of aspiration, and lack of aspiration is, of course, one of the causes of passivity.”

What on earth does this quote mean? I'm literally confused between either the lifestyles (classes) in which people live their lives today, or how people suffer penalties from getting into things just as they’re falling apart. I could be wrong on both though. Any light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without further context, I'd have to say the passage's meaning lies in something like the following progression.

1. One lives to be admired by others.
2. Flattery is the expression of admiration.
3. Having been flattered, and so having achieved said admiration, one becomes sated, as a hungry man does after a full meal.
4. Having become sated, one ceases to try, and hence becomes passive and possibly indolent.

Comment: Excellent response Robusto.

Answer (score 3):

It says, if people tell you that you are awesome then you'll have less reason to do attempt anything worthwhile.

Comment: Yes, I got a better understanding of it thanks. People such as myself, often goes passive and lose intuition when they put to much admiration into their focuses. Sorta like gaining nothing from nothing I guess.

Comment: As Robusto points out, this quote appears to apply to people who live to be admired by others. People who don't care all that much about what others think of them can't be thus affected. Those who live to satisfy themselves by seeing that what they do is actually worth doing and beneficial to others besides themselves don't revel in flattery. If flattery makes you cringe with embarrassment instead of smile with vainglory, then you will be generally immune to the diseases of passivity, indolence, and hubris.

Comment: @BillFranke I haven't read the book, but it seems to me that it is a attacking flatterers not the flattered. For example, it could be talking about schooling a child, and telling someone not to tell the child that everything they do is good.

Comment: @Lucas: You might be right about that. I haven't looked up the book. But young children and those who lack self-confidence and self-esteem are perfect targets for flatterers. You might want to develop your cryptic answer to clearly explain what it means. Your sentence in the above comment is clear and meaningful, but using the clichéd "If someone tells you that you're awesome" is murky. I don't recommend such a cavalier attitude when answering questions about meaning: that merely generates more questions about meaning. :-)

Comment: @BillFranke Yeah, I don't usually do it, but I was inspired formality of the other answer. If I was feeling argumentative I could go all post-modern and argue that there is no *actual* meaning and the best we can do for such questions, as a Q&A community, is collect a diverse set of interpretations. But I haven't got the energy to fight it out. I also reckon you have a point worth making and I don't want to seem like I disagree ;)

Comment: @Lucas: Postmodern is totally bogus, dude. Those phonies are out to impress themselves & the rest of the world with their pointless intellectual gymnastics. Whether there is actual meaning in words or not is irrelevant. It's all about what we agree on. It's just an article of faith & a necessary condition for continuing to exist. "Life, friends, is boring. We must not say so." Postmodernist mental contortionists are sideshow freaks even more bored with life than our current crop of jr & sr high schoolers these days. Indiscriminate collecting is pointless. It's OK to disagree w/me. Many do. :-)

Comment: @BillFranke Well, that's just, like, your opinion, man. To be honest, I have never witnessed anything from postmodernism but people trying wholeheartedly to get at hard to express and unpopular truths, with others being completely uncharitable towards them. I guess there could be a load of bogosity, but I haven't really seen it. Anyway, postmodernism aside, I agree we should not be indiscriminate, but nor should we expect a singular, definitive and unambiguous answer. Some (but not an excessive amount of diversity) of mode and content is needed (an indeed promoted by SE). But we both know that

Comment: @Lucas: Yes, of course it's just my opinion. And what you said was just your opinion. That's an unpopular truth as well. Most people think they know "The Truth", but... What cannot be disputed are facts. Facts are trivial, but what they mean -- i.e., just our opinion about the significance of facts -- is what the ruckus is about. It's all ideology & religion. Postmodernism is up there with L Ron Hubbardism. Read about the [Sokal Affair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokal_affair) -- surely you've already done so -- & consider what it means about how PM distorts semantics & misuses language.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7177/discussion-between-lucas-and-bill-franke)

Comment: @Lucas: Thank you for the invitation, but I don't have time to chat right now -- I have to leave to visit a friend and his daughter in a few minutes -- and I'm way behind in my editing. :-)

Comment: @BillFranke no worries, our discussion was just getting rather out of hand for a comment thread so I clicked the link. I guess the room will remain if you wish to respond in the future - I don't know, I've never used it before.